# Excel 2007 VBA: Performance on SelectionChange event

Tags: performance, vba, excel, excel-2007

Is there a way to improve performance in any meaningful way for the following VBA code in Excel?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Me.Range("Group1"), Target) Is Nothing Then

     With wksData
       .Range("Group1Column").Value = Target.Column
       .Range("Group1Row").Value = Target.Row
     End With
   End If

End Sub
```

I've added conditional formatting that looks at the Group1Column and Group1Row named ranges.  I can't tell if my performance issue is related to the overkill of SelectionChange or the conditional formatting, but there's a noticeable lag that'd I'd like to get rid of.

The conditional formatting is super basic (something like Column($D3) = Group1Column), and it's only for 'eye-candy' purposes, but it would be helpful for the solution overall.

Some things I've tried: .ScreenUpdating, .EnableEvents, .Calculations.  .ScreenUpdating does ensure the user has to wait before selecting their next cell, but not quite what I had in mind.

Any tips would helpful!

Comment: Please define Group1, Group1Column, Group1Row.

Comment: Group1, Group1Column and Group1Row are just named ranges in excel.  Group1 is a range of 3 x 7 cells.  Group1Column is a range to store the current selection's column, and Group1Row is a range that stores the current selection's row.  

I store these values in ranges so that I can use Conditional Formatting.  I suppose it would be possible to replicate the conditional formatting logic entirely in code, but I would like to avoid if possible, I'm not all that sure it would be any faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's lightening fast for me.  Do you have a lot of other calculations going on in the workbook?  What version are you using?

Comment: Huh.  Well, I'll have to do a double-take on this then, as it's definitely not lightning quick for me.  <p>

As far as stats, the workbook has only 29 formulas, and they're non-volatile (just index functions).  I'm on XL 2007, and my system is at 2gigs of RAM, plain ol' intel processor in the 3ghz range...  I am admittedly a bit perplexed.  I'll test and get back.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  Ironically, I stripped the above code down so that it would make sense for my posting, and when I re-tested it (starting from my posted code) it was working as you described it.  I added complexity back to the code as I went, removed some redundancy, tested at each new addition, and now it seems to be working perfectly.  Oh and, ".EnableEvents = False" by itself (no .ScreenUpdating or .Calculation changes) helped trim some microseconds off too.  Thanks again!

Comment: There's nothing worse than tearing something down, building it back up, and not being able to reproduce the problem, :)  But I'm glad you got it working.